# HTTP 404 when accessing .svc file in IIS

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I recently created a WCF service that works fine when tested from Visual Studio 2008. but when I deploy the project to IIS and I try to access the .svc file from IIS, I get this error :

```
"Server Error in '/' Application.The resource cannot be found.  "
```

I've been having this issue for the past 4 days .

in the Handler Mappings of IIS Manager, I can see two entries for .svc :

```
svc-Integrated and svc-ISAPI-2.0
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You need to add a mapping for the SVC extension to ASP.NET.  The easiest way to do this is to run `ServiceModelReg.exe -i` from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation.  You may also need to enable ASP.NET if you haven't already done so.

---

If you are using Windows Server 2012 or 2016, follow these instructions instead:

- [WCF on IIS8; *.svc handler mapping doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116134/wcf-on-iis8-svc-handler-mapping-doesnt-work)

Comment: Did you try restarting IIS afterwards?

Comment: Do you now have a mime mapping for .svc?

Comment: It's not mime mapping- Application Extension Mapping. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752252(v=vs.90).aspx.

Comment: Important: don't do this on Server 2012 with .NET 4.5 installed. It screwed me up until I then ran ServiceModelReg.exe -ua. See here for the Server 2012 solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116134/wcf-on-iis8-svc-handler-mapping-doesnt-work

Answer (score 154):

What worked for me, On Windows 2012 Server R2:

[image: WCF HTTP 404]

Thanks goes to "Aaron D"

Comment: That worked for me on Win10, Win8.1 desktops and Win2012 server :) Thanks!

Comment: That worked for me on Win10, Win8.1 desktops and Win2012 server :) Thanks!

Comment: For some reason, I had to install the feature for 3.5 as well as for 4.5, and via the command line:

`dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:WCF-http-Activation45 /all` 

and also 

`dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:WCF-http-Activation /all`

Comment: Works on Sever 2019 as well

Comment: For me, I cannot install .NET 4.5 > HTTP Activation until I install .NET 3.5 > HTTP Activation and Non-HTTP Activation first.

Comment: dism commands given by @Rocklan works perfectly fine !

Comment: This one worked for me on Windows 11.

Answer (score 60):

I found [these instructions on a blog post](http://www.mohamedibrahim.net/blog/2010/01/24/problems-with-deploying-wcf-services-on-iis-70-or-iis-6-iis-and-other-deployment-options-and-scenarios-visual-studio-net-and-windows-activation-services/) that indicated this step, which worked for me (Windows 8, 64-bit):

> Make sure that in windows features, you have both WCF options under .Net framework are ticked. So go to Control Panel –> Programs and Features –> Turn Windows Features ON/Off –> Features –> Add Features –> .NET Framework X.X Features. Make sure that .Net framework says it is installed, and make sure that the WCF Activation node underneath it is selected (checkbox ticked) and both options under WCF Activation are also checked.
>
> ```
> These are:
> * HTTP Activation
> * Non-HTTP Activation
> Both options need to be selected (checked box ticked).
> ```

Comment: If I could upvote this more than once I would, this was driving me NUTS, cheers!

Answer (score 6):

I see you've already solved your problem - but for posterity:

We had a similar problem, and the SVC handler was already correctly installed. Our problem was the ExtensionlessUrl handler processing requests before they reached the SVC handler.

To check this - in Handler Mappings in IIS Manager at the web server level, view the list of handlers in order (it's an option on the right-hand side). If the various ExtensionlessUrl handlers appear above the SVC handlers, then repeatedly move them down until they're at the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

None of the above solutions resolved this error for me. I had to set the following in web.config:

```
system.servicemodel > bindings > webHttpBinding > binding:
```

```xml
<security mode="Transport">
  <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
</security>
```

I would like to take this opportunity to CURSE Microsoft once again for creating  such a huge mess with the .NET Framework and making developer lives so miserable for so long!

Comment: I'll drink to that!  Microsoft's solution to WCF configuration crazed issue was to kill the product in .NET Core.

Comment: I've since moved to Go and I'll never go back. If you ever worked with classic ASP , it was simple and worked without hiccups or waiting for the .NET JIT to lazy-compile web pages. Go is also super fast! It feels just like running a static website.

Comment: What about Rust? Heard good things, but also heard some horrible things such as code bloat and fake safety.

Comment: I had a look at Rust too. It's becoming hugely popular now, especially running in the browser via WebAssembly (crazy fast! see https://www.arewewebyet.org/) but for me the learning curve was a lot higher than Go. I actually learned Go in a couple of days and it's also super fast, both at run-time and compiling your project. Both of these languages are light-years ahead of JIT based compilers like .NET and JVM.

Answer (score 1):

Verifies that you directory has been converted into an Application is your IIS.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem today.

For me, the solution was to go into IIS, right-click on the new Web Site name, select Properties, ASP.Net, and change the ASP.Net version from "1.1.4322" (which it had set as the default) to 2.0.50727.

Once I'd done that, I could right-click on the .svc file, click on "Browse" and see the friendly Service webpage.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 .net framework version are given under the features in add role/ features in server 2012

a. 3.5

b. 4.5

Depending up on used framework you can enable [HTTP-Activation](http://www.asptricks.net/2015/04/wcf-svc-404-not-found.html) under WCF services. :)

Comment: This works for Windows Server 2016 & 2019 (hadn't tried the latest version) as well.

Answer (score 1):

This can also become an issue after enabling IIS 6 Management Compatibility in windows 10. Setting the framework HTTP Activation under WCF Services will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error was caused by incorrect mapping settings in the file applicationhost.config (\System32\inetsrv\config). For some reason, Visual Studio 2013 corrupted it while creating a virtual directory in IIS. The fix was to manually edit the sites section in the file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case Win 10. the file applicationHost.config is corrupted by VS 2012. And you can get the copy the history of this file under C:\inetpub\history. Then restart IIS and it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the extension .svc to the allowed extensions in the request filtering settings (got 404.7 errors before).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding the .svc suffix as allowed in request filtering did the trick for me.