# missing .net framework 2.0 for svc

Tags: iis

In my IIS 7.0, it only has svc-ISAP-4.0_32bit, svc-ISAP-4.0_64bit, and svc-integrated-4.0.

Missing the 2.0. How can I add this?

System info:

- IIS7
- Win 7 ultimate
- VS 2008 Prof

Answer (score 1):

You can try these questions answers [HTTP 404 when accessing .svc file in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609377/http-404-when-accessing-svc-file-in-iis).

In short the problem is that IIS ASP.net and what not was installed after installing Visual Studio not before and the mappins don't get registered.

What solved it for me is running:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation\ServiceModelReg.exe -i
```