# HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found when accesing SVC service

Tags: iis-8

I have REST service application which is hosted in an IIS 8 in a Windows 8 PC. When I request the service I am getting an error as follows ... HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found.

Here is the detailed error message.

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Most likely causes:
•The directory or file specified does not exist on the Web server.
•The URL contains a typographical error.
•A custom filter or module, such as URLScan, restricts access to the file.

Things you can try:
•Create the content on the Web server.
•Review the browser URL.
•Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code and see which module is calling SetStatus. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click here. 

Detailed Error Information:
Module   IIS Web Core 
Notification   MapRequestHandler 
Handler   StaticFile 
Error Code   0x80070002 

Requested URL   http://IP.com/Wining/RService.svc/general 

Physical Path   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Wining\RService.svc\general 

Logon Method   Anonymous 

Logon User   Anonymous
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is too little info to give any useful feedback. What have you tried? What tutotial do you follow?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTTP 404 when accessing .svc file in IIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609377/http-404-when-accessing-svc-file-in-iis)

Comment: Currently I am using this WCF REST application in IIS 7. Now I have moved this to a IIS8 which is in a Windows 8 PC. Now this is not working and throwing the above error message.

Answer (score 4):

There are myriads of possible causes. In general, the target resource at given URL is not found, so it may be simply missing, misconfigured, not started, etc. First - check the server logs, they usually contain more detailed information about the issue.

Also, please doublecheck that the service really is up and running. Connect to the www server and check it via localhost not `ip.com`.

I'm not an expert, but judging from the snippet you provided, it seems to be WCF service, the `Handler: StaticFile` seems very odd. It seems like the IIS misinterpretes your request as a StaticFile (a resource read from the disks and just passed-through without any further processing) which for me seems perfectly wrong.

You may have not installed the service properly, or have url mappings and/or handlers messed up, or you may even have NET/ASP framework not properly installed.. What have you installed first? .Net or IIS?

check similar questios, there are many.. for example:

[WCF on IIS8; *.svc handler mapping doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116134/wcf-on-iis8-svc-handler-mapping-doesnt-work)

[HTTP 404 when accessing .svc file in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609377/http-404-when-accessing-svc-file-in-iis?lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

I had to enable HTTP Activation in .NET Framework 4.5 Advanced Services > WCF Services (running on WIndows 2012) and after an IISReset it worked fine.