# Host Website in IIS having WCF Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, wcf, iis

I have a website which contains one WCF service. I dont have separate WCF Project for that. when working locally it works fine. Now I want to host that website in IIS It is showing 404 (Not Found)

> http://arapl-ws-08/ARAPLWeb/wcf/ExposureService.svc/InitializeGrid 404 (Not Found)

this is the folder structure after hosting website
[image]

in web.config I have mentioned service model like this

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WebHttpEndpointBinding">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="Windows" />
            <!--<transport clientCredentialType="Windows"  />-->
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ARAPL">
          <endpointDiscovery enabled="false" />
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>

      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WCFWindowsBasicHttpBinding.Service1Behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceAuthenticationManager authenticationSchemes="Negotiate" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>

      <service name="RiskAnalytics.Web.wcf.ExposureService" behaviorConfiguration="WCFWindowsBasicHttpBinding.Service1Behavior">
        <endpoint address="" name="webHttpEndpoint" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebHttpEndpointBinding" behaviorConfiguration="ARAPL" contract="RiskAnalytics.Web.wcf.IExposureService">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>

    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: sounds like an IIS config issue. take a look at this question and see if anything helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609377/http-404-when-accessing-svc-file-in-iis

Comment: @Jay thanks will look into it

Comment: Did you try "http://arapl-ws-08/ARAPLWeb/wcf/ExposureService.svc" in browser (omitting operation name)??

Comment: @Viru yes it is saying 404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: WCF 4 needs to be manually registered on IIS if on Windows 7 or Server 2008 R2.

Comment: @Jay http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609377/http-404-when-accessing-svc-file-in-iis this solved my problem .. answer given by Aaron D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> this solved my problem. In fusture if anyone got an issue refer this

I found these instructions on a blog post that indicated this step, which worked for me (Windows 8, 64-bit):

Make sure that in windows features, you have both WCF options under .Net framework are ticked.

> So go to Control Panel –> Programs and Features –> Turn Windows
>   Features ON/Off –> Features –> Add Features –> .NET Framework X.X
>   Features. Make sure that .Net framework says it is installed, and make
>   sure that the WCF Activation node underneath it is selected (checkbox
>   ticked) and both options under WCF Activation are also checked.

These are:

```
* HTTP Activation
* Non-HTTP Activation
```

Both options need to be selected (checked box ticked).